# Is there any inbuilt pandas operation which can find similar columns of two different dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, word2vec, tf-idf

I have two dataframes which have similar data in the columns but different column names. I need to identify if they are similar columns or not.

`colName1=['movieName','movieRating','movieDirector','movieReleaseDate']`

`colName2=['name','release_date','director']`

My approach tokenize colName1 and compare them using
 - levenshtein/Jaccard Distance
 - Find similarity using TFIDF score.

But this works for col names having similar names for eg. movieName and Name. Suppose you have 'IMDB_Score' and 'average_rating' this approach is not going to work.

Is there any way word2vec can be utilized in the above mentioned problem.

Comment: maybe you should get values from columns - `df[colName1]`